# Django for-loop activates view multiple times when a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I've been working on something of a blog site and on it of course you would post things. I have an index.html where I have this:

```
{% for post in posts %} {% include "blog/featuredpost.html" %} {% endfor %}
```

I've also used Django pagination.
Now, what I want to make is a like and dislike button which is reusable, meaning I would probably want it in "blog/featuredpost.html". So, that's what I've done.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <div id="divLikes" class="col-sm-6 bg-success text-center">
        Likes: {{ post.likes }}
    </div>
    <div id="divDislikes" class="col-sm-6 bg-danger text-center text-block">
        Dislikes: {{ post.dislikes }}
    </div>
</div>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <form id="like_form" action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button id="like_button" type="submit" value="vote" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span> Like
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></span> Dislike
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm btn-block">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" aria-hidden="true"></span> Comment
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

---

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       //$('#like_button').click(function(){ }); 
/* The for cycle sends all the posts id that should appear on the page. 
It should send just the one on which the like button is clicked. */
$(document).on('submit', '#like_form', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '{% url "like" %}',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
        LikeId: {{ post.id }},
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $('#divLikes').load(' #divLikes', function() { 
            /* It's important to add the space before #divLikes, I don't know why */
            $(this).children().unwrap()
        })
    }
});
```

})

views.py

```
def view_like(request):
# AJAX Like Button
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        likepostId = request.POST.get('LikeId', '')
        print(likepostId)
        likepost = get_object_or_404(Post, id=likepostId)

        print(likepost.title + " has " + str(likepost.likes))

        response_data = {}
        return JsonResponse(response_data)
else: 
    raise Http404

return 200
```

I currently have it so it would just print out certain things. On the front page it actually just replicates the html/css part due to the AJAX success function. How do I make the like button specifically know that I want a like on the certain post that I've clicked on? Because, as it is now, it just spams all of the id's of all the other posts on the page, in no particular order.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have there a bunch of nodes with the same id (`#like_form` and `#like_button`), and you add event to all of them. It's not allowed to have multiple elements with the same value of `id`. 
Remove the attribute `id` from `form`, change the `button`'s `id` to `class`, and set its value to id of the post, ie.:

```
<button type="submit" value="{{ post.id }}" class="vote_button btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block">
```

then hook the event to the class `.vote_button`, and submit its value (so the `data.LikeId` in your `ajax` request will be something like `$(event.target).val()` ) to idenfity which post you voted one

edit:

the javascript will roughly look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".vote_button").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url "like" %}',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
            LikeId: $(event.target).val(),
        },
        success: function(response) {
            /* I am not sure what is this supposed to do
               load() expects url as the first parameter, not a node
            */
            $('#divLikes').load('#divLikes', function() { 
                $(this).children().unwrap()
            })
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I sort of see what you're telling me, but I don't know what "hook the event to the class" means. I have little to no experience with javascript and ajax, so, if you wouldn't mind, could you correctly fix my script? And, from what I gather, you're saying that #like_form isn't needed because javascript already understands vote_button, because as you said, it should be bound. Anyway, thanks you, sincerely.

Comment: Instead of showing the five posts on the page, not it shows the one that is clicked but five times. And, also the success function is supposed to refresh the div, so it changes Likes 0 to Likes 1

Comment: I solved the problem by making the vote_button class be named vote_button{{post.id}}, this way we have a class with an ID behind it, making it work for each individual post.